# Increased voting privileges as you prove yourself

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting

It appears that the more accepted moderator flags you raise, the more moderator flags you are allowed to raise each day; therefore, could other activities be made consistent with this?

For example:

Could the allowed number of votes increase, for example if you reach n votes, if x percentage have been down votes and it is obvious you are not "collecting badges"

Comment: More votes would allow certain users to get a disproportionately large influence on SO. I would not encourage that.

Comment: @Bart - how so?

Comment: How does one make it obvious that they're not collecting badges? The system can't possibly determine that fairly.

Comment: One option would be to give more votes to users who already have all the badges and still keep using up all their votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [vote <strike>a lot</strike> the most,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130540/ward) and I wouldn't want any more.

Maybe SO, with its huge question volume, could benefit from some people having more than 40 votes, but on any other site, 40 per day is plenty.  If you actually read questions and answers, it takes time to cast 40 votes, so increasing the number goes against the SE idea of encouraging people to have some balance in their lives.

Since the "highest" badge for voting only takes 600 votes, if something like this were going to be done, I'd set the bar really high: something like an extra 5 votes per day for every 10,000 votes cast, but probably cap it at 50 votes per day.

Comment: plus you only get 40 votes if 10 of your votes are for questions. If you were to vote on only answers, you'd get 30 votes.